# Java: locking for editing and updating

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking

So the gist of my problem is - I have a class that extends JPanel, it also has many other swing/awt components in it. It is displaying some data from DB. It does something along the line of

```
public class DataPanel extends JPanel
{
Lock lock;

public DataPanel()
{
lock = new Reenntractlock();
//init
}
public void update()
{
    if(!lock.trylock())return;
    //do update

    lock.unlock();
}
public void edit()
{
    lock.lock();
    //etc etc
    commit();
}
public void commit()
{
    //etc etc;

    lock.unlock();
}
}
```

I have an event listener such that whenever a button is clicked, it calls on edit. When another button is clicked, it calls on commit. The update method will be called on periodically by timer scheduler (Timer class)

What I want to accomplish

(1) have the update and edit/commit be mutually exclusive. No concurrent update or edit/commit allowed.
(2) have the update operation defers until the user stops edit/commit

My question

(1) Is this correct? Will it do what I intend to? I have tested it a bit and it looks fine but I am not sure. (2) Is there better way to accomplish this

Edit: code updated

Comment: You don't need to lock the lock to lock it.  You should either use `synchronized` on an Object (which isn't a Lock) or use the Lock API, but not both.

Comment: You're not using the `ReentrantLock` object correctly, you don't need to `synchronize` on it, you simply call the `lock()` and `unlock()` methods.

Comment: Edited. Thank you for pointing that out